# Electron: app is undefined but imported correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I run main.js the app variable is undefined although it was imported correctly, I was told to do it using the require function and to import it alongside BrowserWindow, which I did, but it still comes up as undefined both in the console log and in the error, my Electron version is 27.0.0 and my Node.js version is 18.18.1

```
[Running] node "c:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\ElectronApp\main.js"
undefined

c:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\ElectronApp\main.js:5
app.whenReady(() => {
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'whenReady')
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\ElectronApp\main.js:5:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.18.1

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.327 seconds
```

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

console.log(app+"\n");

app.whenReady(() => {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height:600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  window.loadFile("index.html")
})
```

Comment: Is the second line the output of `console.log(app+"\n")`? It looks like you're setting `app` to the pathname of `electron.exe`, not an object.

Comment: You need to require each electron module individually. Try `const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')`. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-first-app#importing-modules

Comment: @Timur I've changed it to that and now the "app" variable is undefined

Comment: Don't run your script with `node`. You're writing an electron app, so run it with `electron` (or `npx electron` if you wisely didn't install electron globally)